# how can I make a drop-down menu in html

Tags: html, forms, select, drop-down-menu, html-select

By using the <select>  and <option> tags I am finding it extremely difficult to make this example drop down list/menu in my HTML SoloLearn intro course

It's asking me to :

1. Add a drop-down menu using the **<select>** tag to offer your customers more than one **<option>**. Insert the drop-down menu inside the **form** container tag, right below the h2 heading.

My initial code was this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Product Name</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>New Awesome Product</h1>
  <img src="https://blob.sololearn.com/courses/np.png">
  <!-- explanation of the core product-->
  <p>Introducing our <strong>latest product</strong>, designed to make your life <em>easier</em> and <u>more efficiant.</u></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Feature 1</li>
    <li>Feature 2</li>
    <li>Feature 3</li>
  </ul>
  <form>
    <h2>Order now!</h2>

    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nm"><br>
    <br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="em"><br>
    <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried using ChatGPT and I ask for some html code that includes a drop list list menu using the `<select>` and `<option>` tags. then I asked it to Make a drop down menu in html that lets users know about sizes and colors and then I finally asked it to include the `<form> </form>` tags and now my html code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Product Name</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>New Awesome Product</h1>
  <img src="https://blob.sololearn.com/courses/np.png">
  <!-- explanation of the core product-->
  <p>Introducing our <strong>latest product</strong>, designed to make your life <em>easier</em> and <u>more efficiant.</u></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Feature 1</li>
    <li>Feature 2</li>
    <li>Feature 3</li>
  </ul>
  <form>
    <h2>Order now!</h2>
    <label for="size">Size:</label>
    <select id="size" name="size">
      <option value="small">Small</option>
    </select>

    <label for="color">Color:</label>
    <select id="color" name="color">
      <option value="red">Red</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nm"><br>
    <br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="em"><br>
    <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Basic & easy method of creating a dropdown menu in HTML is using `select` ,`option`. You can add additional CSS to it if any different styles required

Comment: What is the actual question here? PS: Your second code was missing a `<html>`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `<select>` and `<option>` tag for that.

Snippet for using  and

```html
<!-- All of your options would be inside the select tag -->
<select> 
<!-- Add you options in option tag -->
<option value="option1"> Option 1 </option>
<-- here value can be used to capture particular option provided -->
<option value="option2"> Option 2 </option>
</select>
```

Checkout this code:

```html
  <label for="features">Choose a feature:</label>
  <select name="features">
    <option value="feature1">Feature 1</option>
    <option value="feature2">Feature 2</option>
    <option value="feature2">Feature 3</option>
  </select>
```

For more reference, visit [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

The complete code would be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Product Name</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>New Awesome Product</h1>
  <img src="https://blob.sololearn.com/courses/np.png">
  <!-- explanation of the core product-->
  <p>Introducing our <strong>latest product</strong>, designed to make your life <em>easier</em> and <u>more efficiant.</u></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Feature 1</li>
    <li>Feature 2</li>
    <li>Feature 3</li>
  </ul>
  <form>
    <h2>Order now!</h2>
    <label for="features">Choose a feature:</label>
    <select name="features">
      <option value="feature1">Feature 1</option>
      <option value="feature2">Feature 2</option>
      <option value="feature2">Feature 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nm"><br>
    <br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="em"><br>
    <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The complete code would be

Comment: That is a very poor resource  - I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) instead, also it is not answering the question

Comment: At least use their example instead of cutting and pasting from w3schools, which may be beginner friendly but I find dangerous since it teaches beginners poor coding

Comment: @mplungjan, please check it again now.

Comment: Please add a `Please select` with an empty option

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for the feedback, I improvised it.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dropdown just use `<select>` and `<option>`:

```
<select name="document-list">
      <option value="pan">PAN Card</option>
      <option value="aadhar">Aadhar Card</option>
      <option value="dl">Driving License</option>
</select>
```

This will simply create a dropdown for you and can style the way you want.